# How to create a constrained HList from a sequence?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a constructor that has the following signature:

```
class Event[DL <: HList](
  detailsIn: DL
)(implicit lbcr: LUBConstraint[DL, EventDetail[_]]) { ...
```

In the companion object I have:

```
  def apply[DL <: HList](
    detailIn: String*
  )(implicit lbcr: LUBConstraint[DL, EventDetail[String]]) =
    new Event(
      if (detailIn.map(deet => EventDetail(deet)).toList.size == 1)
        detailIn.map(deet => EventDetail(deet)).toList.toHList[String :: HNil].get
      else throw new NotImplementedException()
    )(lbcr)
```

Admittedly, this apply method could be cleaned up.

This yields the following error which I'm frankly lost about how to deal with:

```
Error:(87, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.LUBConstraint[DL,edu.cornell.ansci.dairy.econ.model.event.EventDetail[String]]
 required: shapeless.LUBConstraint[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil],edu.cornell.ansci.dairy.econ.model.event.EventDetail[_]]
```

The second part of the issue: is there any way to make this polymorphic over the size of detailIn? Based on my other readings, I assume not, and I can think of no way to do it in Scala. The best I can do is to support for convenience a fixed number lengths for detailIn string sequences, and if that is exceeded, the user of the class must use HList directly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be scared by that type error, it's pretty explicit, let me try to type the body of your `apply` method bottom up:

At the very bottom you have a `String :: HNil`:

```
val e0: String :: HNil = e.toList.toHList[String :: HNil].get
```

The `if` doesn't change that:

```
val e1: String :: HNil = 
  if (???) e0
  else throw new NotImplementedException()
```

Thus, when you create `Event`, `Event.DL = String :: HNil`:

```
new Event[String :: HNil](e1)(lbcr)
```

But `lbcr` has type `LUBConstraint[DL, _]`, that's incompatible with `LUBConstraint[String :: HNil, _]`!

For the second part of your question, shapeless provides a safer alternative to varargs: [ProductArgs](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d27c58fede7655938d91631c6adc2f7a7c4ceea7/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlists.scala#L212-L234). Backed by a macro and a slightly more involved definition, `object myfunction extends ProductArgs { def applyProduct[L <: HList](args: L) }` instead of `def myfunction(args: Any*)`, you can get your varargs as an `HList` instead of a `Seq[String]`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, I had a few other issues with the above (need to replace `_` with `T <: Any` being the main one). I've got it typechecking at least, will keep playing with it to get it in a usable state and update when I do.